# WL1837MOD SDIO Control(or Wifi module in general)

Tags: driver, wifi, texas-instruments, sdio

There are a number of wifi module which are controlled by SDIO(as an option). I am using the WL1837MOD as a specific example but I welcome more general answers.

All the documentation for this chip references the linux drivers which aren't my interest - I am interested in bare-metal and understanding direct control and crafting custom Layer 2 packets.

Where do I find information on low level SDIO control of this device? Or any of these WIFI modules? Pretty much every single one of the WIFI modules I have looked at don't include a data-sheet which actually goes over direct device commands. They simply reference the linux driver.

Comment: Like this . ? . ? https://mysupport.zyxel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012079580--AP-How-to-configure-a-Guest-Wi-Fi-using-layer-2-isolation

Comment: level 2 means layer 2 OSI model, in particular crafting 802.11 frames(correct term instead of packet I guess).

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000029638/network-and-io/wireless.html